# Create Raid1 on running ubuntu 20.04 system

Tags: raid

I want to create RAID1 on my running Ubuntu server 20.04. to be more specific, I want to create raid1 with sda(where my system is running) and sdb. The two HDD are 1 TB. I think the tutorials and documentation are taking about raid1 with sdb and sdc which are not the same running system.

Can I achieve such thing, Where its achievable in Ubuntu 16 and previous versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 16. might you mean 16.04?

Comment: Yeah its 16.04. Its just for explanation. but I am using Ubunto 20.04 @David

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured it out, by doing Raid1 while I install Ubuntu server then I copied my data from a backup disk.